# ES2015, Browserfy error - Super expression must be either null or a function, not undefined

Tags: gruntjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I am new to ES2015, and a little new to Grunt as well.   I am trying to build a simple application using classes and some inheritance.    I have set up all my files in one directory to make things easy.

I am trying to use browserify task in grunt to compile my ES2015 code down into ES5 code, and that "works"  - however, when I run the application, I keep getting a *Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined* error.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "GruntDemo-Repo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Ryan DesRoches",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies" : {
      "grunt" :                       "*",
      "grunt-contrib-cssmin":         "*",
      "grunt-contrib-sass":           "*",
      "css-condense":                   "*",
      "grunt-contrib-uglify":         "*",
      "grunt-contrib-jshint":           "*",
      "logfile-grunt":              "*",
      "babelify":                       "*",
      "grunt-browserify":           "*",
      "babel-preset-es2015":            "*",
      "react":                      "*",
      "matchdep":                     "*"
  }
}
```

My gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
// Load in all dependencies
"use strict";
require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

// Save a log file of the grunt output - useful for htmlhint
require('logfile-grunt')(grunt,  { filePath: './logs/grunt-task.log', clearLogFile: true });

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // HTML Hint 
    // Description:  check HTML and PhP for common validation and standard issues set in the Options section.
    //
    // Output:  None, errors are logged in the log/grunt-task.log file 
    //
    htmlhint: {
        build: {
            options: {
                'tag-pair': true,                    // Force tags to have a closing pair
                'tagname-lowercase': true,           // Force tags to be lowercase
                'attr-lowercase': true,              // Force attribute names to be lowercase e.g. <div id="header"> is invalid
                'attr-value-double-quotes': true,    // Force attributes to have double quotes rather than single
                'doctype-first': false,              // Force the DOCTYPE declaration to come first in the document 
                'spec-char-escape': false,           // Force special characters to be escaped - Php vars cause issues for now.
                'id-unique': true,                   // Prevent using the same ID multiple times in a document
                'head-script-disabled': true,        // Prevent script tags being loaded in the head for performance reasons
                'style-disabled': true,              // Prevent style tags. CSS should be loaded through 
                "inline-style-disabled": true,       // Prevent inline styles
                "space-tab-mixed-disabled": "space", // Spaces for indentation, not tabs
                "attr-no-duplication" : true         // An attribute cannot be used twice in same element.
            },
            src: ['code/php/**/*.html',
                  'code/php/**/*.php',
                  '!**/SCCS/*'
                  ]
        }
    },


    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // JS Hint 
    // Description: Check JavaScript and JQuery for common validation and standard issues set in the Options section.
    //
    // Output:  None, errors are logged in the log/grunt-task.log file 
    //
    jshint: {
        build: {
            options: {
                globals: {
                    'jQuery':   true,       // Allow the global variable JQuery
                    '$':        false       // do not override the $ global variable.
                },
                'browser':      true,       // Allows for browser globals like document, navigator, etc
                'jquery':       true,       // Allow for jQuery globals
                'curly' :       true,       // Require curly braces around blocks/loops
                'freeze':       true,       // Prohibit overwriting of native objects such as arrays, date, etc
                'latedef':      true,       // Prohibit use of variables before they are defined
                'nonbsp':       true,       // Warn about non-breaking whitespace characters
                'undef':        true,       // Warn about the use of undeclared variables
                'unused':       true        // Warn about variables that are defined, but unused.  
            },
            src: [  'php/public/**/*.js',
                    '!**/*.min.js',         // Ignore files that have been minimized,
                    '!**/jquery.*',         // Ignore JQuery libraries
                    '!**/DEFAULT/**/*',     // DEFAULT has a lot of errors, ignore for now
                    '!**/gdk/**/*',         // ignore GDK files, not sure what they do.
                    '!**/css/**/*',         // Ignore css files
                    '!**/SCCS/*'            // Ignore bitkeeper file
                ]   

        }
    },

    browserify: {   
        dist: {
              options: {
                transform: [
                    ["babelify", {
                        "presets": ["es2015"]
              }]
           ]
        },
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'php/public',
                    src: [
                        '**/*.es2015.js',        // just fine ES2015 js
                        '!**/gdk/**/*',         // ignore GDK files, not sure what they do.
                        '!**/css/**/*',         // Ignore css files
                        '!**/SCCS/*'            // Ignore bitkeeper file
                        ],
                    dest: 'php/public',
                    ext:'.js',
                    extDot: 'first'
                }]
        }   
    },

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // Uglify
    // Description:  Minimizes and consolidates JavaScript files into smaller combined files (per recipie)
    //
    // Output: A minimized Javascript file with a .min.js extention saved to the build/public directories
    //
    uglify: {
        min_a: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'php/public',
                src: [
                    '**/*.js',
                    '!**/*.es2015.js',      // ignore ES2015 scripts
                    '!**/gdk/**/*',         // ignore GDK files, not sure what they do.
                    '!**/css/**/*',         // Ignore css files
                    '!**/SCCS/*'            // Ignore bitkeeper file
                    ],
                dest: 'build/public/js/',
                ext:'.min.js',
                extDot: 'first'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            sourceMap:                  true,
            sourceMapIncludeSources:    true,
            sourceMapUrl: 'build/js'
        }
    },

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // Saas
    // Description:  Converts SASS code into CSS.  
    //
    // Output:  CSS code in the php/public/css folder
    //
    // 
    sass: {
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'php/public',
                src: [
                    '**/*.scss', 
                    '**/*.sass',
                    '!**/SCCS/*',
                    '!**/js/**/*',          // Ignore js files
                    ],
                dest: 'php/public',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            trace:          true,
            lineNumbers:    true, 
        }
    },

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // Cssc
    // Description:  Searches CSS code and consolidates CSS rules and media-queries.  
    //
    // Output:  CSS code in the build/public/css/clean/ folder
    //
    // 
    cssc: {
        build: {
            options: {
                debugInfo:                  true,
                consolidateViaDeclarations: true,
                consolidateViaSelectors:    false,  // This throws and error for some reason
                consolidateMediaQueries:    true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'php/public/',
                src: [
                    '**/css/**/*.css', 
                    '**/css/**/*.css.php', 
                    '!**/DEFAULT/**/*',     // Some DEFAULT files have CSS errors that cause this task to fail
                    '!**/js/**/*',          // Ignore js files
                    '!**/SCCS/*',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/globalstylesmain.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/jquery.qtip2.1.1.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/colorbox.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/staticmain.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/playmain.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/pollsandsurverysmain.css', 
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/OriginalStylesMain.css', 
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/tablesorter.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.css', 
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/jquery.tooltip.css',
                    '**/DEFAULT/css/ilottery/*.css'
                    ],
                dest: 'build/public/css/clean/',
            }]
        }
    },

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // Cssmin
    // Description:  Takes the CSS that has been cleaned by CSSC and consolidates and minimizes it
    //
    // Output:  CSS code in the build/public/css/min folder
    //
    // 
    cssmin: {
        MaineGlobal: 
        {
            options: {
                banner: '/* Minified on <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")%> by GruntJS-cssmin */',
                sourceMap:  true,
                advanced: true,
                mediaMerging: true,   // Merge Media Queries

            },
            files: { 
                    'build/public/css/min/MaineLottery/final.min.css' : [
                        'build/css/clean/MaineLottery/**/*.css', 
                        'build/css/clean/MaineLottery/**/*.css.php', 
                        '!build/css/clean/MaineLottery/**/images.css.php',
                        '!**/js/**/*',          // Ignore js files
                        '!**/SCCS/*'
                    ],      
            }
        }
    },

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // imagemin
    // Description:  Takes any PNG, GIF, or JPEG and compresses them into a new file
    //
    // Output:  Compressed images in the build/public/ folder
    //
    // 
    imagemin: {  
        options: {
            cache: false,
            optimizationLevel: 7                // Optimization levels can go from 1-7, with 7 being the highest optimization. 
            // use: [pngquant(), mozjpeg(), gifsicle()] //  Use the special optimizers for each file.  
        }, 
        dist: {
            files: 
            [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'php/public/',
                src: [
                    '**/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
                    '!**/SCCS/*'
                    ],
                dest: 'build/public',
            }]

        }
    },

    //**************************************************************************************************************************************
    // Watch
    // Description:  On a file save, it will perform mutiple commands depending on the type of file saved. 
    //
    // Output:  Depends on file that is saved.
    //
    // 
    watch: {
        html: {
            files: ['/php/tmpl/**/*.html', '/php/tmpl/**/*.php'],
            tasks: ['htmlhint']
        },
        css: {
            files: ['php/public/sass/**/*.scss', 'php/public/sass/**/*.sass', 'php/public/**/css/**/*.css', 'php/public/**/css/**/*.css.php'],
            tasks: ['buildcss']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['php/public/**/js/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint', 'babel', 'uglify']
        },
        images: {
            files: ['php/public/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            tasks: ['imagemin:single'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,           // don't spawn child processes
            }
        }
    } // end watch          
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);
grunt.registerTask('buildcss',  ['sass', 'cssc', 'cssmin']);


}
```

And then my code I have thrown up on github rather than copy/pasting it here:
https://github.com/MaWebDesigns/Grunt-ES2015-Demo

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Nitpicking but: ES2015 isn't as followed as ES6 so I changed the tag

Comment: Show us the code that throws the error please, not your build chain.

Comment: By "super expression" babel refers to the `extends …` part of a class definition. The error is typically caused by a wrong import/export.

Comment: Yup, you have `export default class DrawGame;` and then `import {DrawGame} from './drawgame.js';`. Those don't match.

Comment: Thanks guys.   That was it, just a typo -  was really convinced it had something to do with my Grunt setup.